# Omit values from a range in NumPy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the following excerpt of code:

```
xmin = -20
xmax = 20
ymin = -20
ymax = 20

x = np.arange(xmin,xmax,0.1)
y = np.arange(ymin,ymax,0.1)
```

I want Python to do all steps BUT the range of -0.1 to 0.1. How do I code this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use boolean indexing on `x` and `y` to omit values in the range -0.1 to 0.1.

For example:

```
x[(x < -0.1) | (x > 0.1)]
```

This gives a view of the array `x` in which all values are either less than -0.1 or greater than 0.1 (i.e. it won't contain the values -0.1, 0, 0.1).

N.B. if your range increments in non-integer values, the use of `np.linspace` is often preferred over `np.arange`.